# Would I be violating terms of service if I asked for permission but got no reply?

Tags: terms-of-service, legal-terms

I created a Python API wrapper for a service, which I want to release as an open source python package if possible but not necessarily, the main issue is that I have a small python project where I need to use their API, not too many requests, if I could release it, that's better. The company is in my country, Lebanon

[The company's terms of service forbid me from doing so](https://www.yamli.com/terms/), but they don't offer a python wrapper in [the first place](https://www.yamli.com/enterprise/).

The company has two founders, one left and one works at google, I tweeted the first, sent a LinkedIn message to the second, asking for permission got no reply. The company has two email addresses, I sent emails to both addresses got no reply.

If the worst case scenario is them blocking my IP address, that's fine, but I wonder if they would be able to pursue legal actions against me even though I went above and beyond trying to ask for their permission without being able to reach them.  Am I still violating their terms of service?\

For example if you use Google translate API for free, you are also violating their TOS, they only block your IP if they detect a large number of API requests and never sue the writer of the library, you could find many free Google translate libraries.

Comment: So your question is basically "if I asked permission to do X, and got no reply, am I now permitted to do X?"

Comment: The web site you linked to has an API page that says it is free. Why not just use that in your Python wrapper? Then you avoid any problem.

Comment: The terms of service you linked to are not the API terms of service. You should read this FAQ item to see how you are allowed to use the API according to them: [FAQ - Are there any restrictions to using the API?](https://www.yamli.com/api/faq/#1.5)

Comment: @Brandin Answering your first question Yes. As for why I asked this question. Here https://www.yamli.com/terms/ 1.2 You agree not to access or attempt to access the Services by any other means other than the interface provided on the Website. You agree not to access or attempts to access the services through any automated means.

Comment: @Brandin The API they  give is very limited, it's just  a JS snippet you could add to any textbox. They don't have a real free api. So I'm afraid I'm violating that section, because I'm doing automated requests and not using the API they offer which is this https://www.yamli.com/api/setup/

Comment: If you want to be in compliance, you need to use their API. If you want to inquire for special permissions, you should use their Contact form (on their site) to ask about that. You should not send such a query via social media (like Twitter or LinkedIn), as the chance of those queries being ignored is too high. If you ask them by a proper means and still get no reply, it does not mean that what you propose is OK.

Comment: "even though I went above and beyond trying to ask for their permission without being able to reach them" - Sending someone a tweet and not getting a reply is definitely not "going above and beyond" trying to ask for permission. Do your due diligence first.

Comment: @Brandin I did send a message through the form and all that

Comment: "I asked if I could borrow his car, but he didn't answer me so I took it anyway"... Unfortunately a non-reply isn't permission, and you can't say "well John lets Jack borrow his car without asking, I'm sure Frank will let me take his", those types of arguments don't work. Just because Google doesn't sue, doesn't mean it is OK to take the resources of other (especially smaller) companies.

Comment: @RonBeyer just to be clear, I was willing to pay them. I'm just clarifying that so I don't sound like a thief

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing though, unfortunately. Just because you intended to pay for the item, but couldn't find anybody to give money to, doesn't mean you can walk out of the store with the item anyway...

Comment: Are you looking for a technical solution in order to use their official API for your use case (Python scripts)? For example Python can interface with a browser, so if you automate actions to a browser and use their API, that would be allowed according to what they wrote on their API pages. I suspect there is also a way to get it to work without a full browser, but this is going into technical areas.  For technical questions like this go to Stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Brandin I solved the problem thanks to you, you pointed out earlier that I could use their API only, so what it means I could use the JS API which they offer only. So I took your advice and found https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py a python library allowing me to execute JavaScript inside Python. Therefore allowing me to use their official API. in fact if you post an answer I would accept it and upvote it, thank you

Comment: @Lynob If that's the case it would be best if you post it as a technical question (e.g. to Stackoverflow.com) and you can also answer your own question as a solution. I searched and found hardly anything on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Releasing a wrapper would not be illegal on its own. If in doubt you could just release it anonymously. T&C's are not worth the paper they're written on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to actively be *given* permission for you to have permission.  If they don't reply you don't have permission and are violating their ToS.